# Stake Pool Locations. How is the best way to obtain a list of cardano stake pools by country?

Tags: stake-pool

I'd like to develop a list of cardano stake pools by country. A static list would be OK, but a repeatable method of developing an updated list by country would be much better. Is there a way of doing this? There are some groovy maps around like The https://input-output-hk.github.io/shelley-node-map/, but a live list by country? Pool explorers dont seem to offer it easily if at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I do not think there is a reliable way to do this.

The recommended best practice is to have the actual block producing node hidden behind two public relay nodes. If the BP and the 2 relays are in three different countries, which country are you going to assign it to?

If a pool operator says their node is for country X but they run their nodes from another country Y, which country are you going to assign it to?

Comment: Makes sense! I guess I am interested in the pools claim to be from country X. So back to the website for that - as you say not particularly reliable.

Comment: You may want to look at some of the web sites like https://pooltool.io which may have country information